# Smallest number in the sequence $9,99,999,9999\cdots$ that is divisible by $p \in \mathbb{P}$.

Tags: functions, modular-arithmetic

To be more precise, $A(p)=\min\{x:p\mid10^x-1\}$ This seems to be different from $φ(p)$ but is always a factor of $φ(p)$. For example, $A(37)=3=φ(37)/12$. I would like to get a clear way of calculating $A(p)$ or a formula for it in terms of $φ(p)$ and other functions.

Comment: Do you mean "is divisible by $p$"?

Comment: There isn't a simple closed formula for the order of $10\pmod p$.  You just have to check the divisors of $p-1$.  Note: I am assuming $p$ is prime, but you don't state that.  For general $n$ you'd need to check the divisors of $\varphi(n)$.

Comment: @lulu That's what I meant.

Comment: what is $p$? ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo A prime number

Comment: Ah, you've discovered the order of an element of a group divides the order of the group itself.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to know is [order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_(group_theory)) of $10$ in $(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^\times$, [group of invertible elements in $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n). Unfortunately, to the best of my knowledge, there is no known formula for this.

However, you correctly noticed that order of $10$ will always be a divisor of $\varphi(p)$. This is direct consequence of [Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)#Applications), order of an element of a group will always divide the order of the group. Since the order of $(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^\times$ is $\varphi(p)$, order of $10$ will divide $\varphi(p)$.

To demonstrate that this is not trivial, I will do it the other way around, for given positive integer $n$, I will find all prime $p$ such that order of $10$ in $(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^\times$ is $n$:

$$\begin{array}{c | c}
n & p\\\hline
1 & 3\\
2 & 11\\
3 & 37\\
4 & 101\\
5 & 41, 271\\
6 & 7, 13\\
7 & 239, 4649\\
8 & 73, 137\\
9 & 333667\\
10 & 9091
\end{array}$$

You can do it yourself by factoring $10^n-1$.